# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.Delete() throws unclear exception

Tags: c#, exception

I'm currently creating an ActiveDirectory management toolkit for the company I work at.

While writing a function to read and process group memberships and their attached nested groups with System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement I get a weird exception thrown.

This is the code:

```
var nestedgroups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
var groups = user.GetGroups();       

try
{
    foreach(Principal p in groups)
    {
        foreach(Principal np in nestedgroups)
            {
                if (p.Equals(np))
                {
                    np.Delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

`nestedgroups` represents the result of UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups();

`groups` represents the result of UserPrincipal.GetGroups();

The functions intended purpose is to remove all principals from `nestedgroups`, which are already present in `groups`. This is done to improve performance in further processing and output of the groups that are assigned to the user in question.

The condition of the if-block is true, so `Principal.Delete();`, aimed at the Principal that's currently processed by the foreach-loop should execute perfectly fine.
And here's where the problems start. as soon as the Delete()-function is supposed to run, it throws the following exception instead:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException' in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: A device attached to the system is not functioning.
```

While the code continues to run, the Principal does not get removed from the collection (correct me, if that's incorrect wording).

I already fed the exception into google, without any success.

I'd be really happy if you could provide me with further resources or tips from your personal experience on how to handle/avoid this error.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the principal from the list instead of deleting it?
Also, you said this is a collection, so I would recommend LINQ here


`var newList = nestedgroups.Where( p1 => !groups.Any(p2 => p2 == p1))`

Comment: @Bobdriving nestedgroups does not offer a remove function. I'm not sure what the type of p and np is. And I'm really not sure, if it really is a collection.

Comment: If it implements IEnumerable you can use LINQ. A collection implements IEnumerable. IList is another data structure that implements IEnumerable. Can you post the data structure that is returned by `user.GetAuthorizationGroups();`?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what do you mean by "data structure"? How do I get that? The tooltip of the function states that it "returns a collection of principal objects that contains all the authorization groups of which this user is a member."

Comment: The function has a return type, I want to see what that class looks like.
"Returns a collection" leads me to believe it is an ICollection (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13(v=vs.110).aspx) but I want to be sure

Comment: Okay, I think the return type is PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> - where "<Principal>" is noted as "<T>" in the description of the class.

Comment: That's obviously a custom class so I'm not sure I can help. Try linq. If that fails, simply create another list and add the correct entries to that list

Swap your IF condition around and instead of deleting from the first list, add to the second

Comment: It is a custom class in that way that it is provided by System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement. I did not create the class myself. Moving the correct/wanted entries to a new list sounds good, tho. I will give that a try. Thank you very much for your help so far! :)

Comment: Let me know if that works for you. If it does I will submit as an answer so you can accept it

Comment: @Bobdriving I couldn't fully implement it yet, but it appears to be working so far. I think that's alright for an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new list and add the valid entries to that list before returning. The original lists do not have to be mutated